# Will WPA Enterprise give any advantage on home network with one user?

Tags: wpa2, wpa2-psk, wpa-enterprise

I understand some of the reasons why WPA Enterprise is more secure from this question: [Why is WPA Enterprise more secure than WPA2?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/35780/37051)

However, given a home network with only one single user where that user has a long and complex password (at least 28 random chars), is there any advantage for WPA Enterprise?

From what I read, I believe that in this specific situation, there is no meaningful advantage for WPA Enterprise. I wonder if the increased complexity of WPA Enterprise might actually work against security in this scenario (single user, home network). Am I right or wrong?

Comment: You said the Network only is a single-user. But does that mean there's only one **device** on the network?

Comment: @Daisetsu - yes, only one wireless access point and only one user. (However, I would be interested in knowing how the answer might change if a second or third wireless access point were added in the future.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main benefit of WPA Enterprise is that it uses a radius server for authentication, which allows you more control on a per user basis.

Each user gets their own key to secure their connection. This means a user can't Snoop on other people using the same network (in WPA2 Personal you can read all users wifi traffic if you have the PSK).

Each user can be assigned a VLAN, further segregating the traffic, and allowing you to partition your network based on the user.

If a device is lost or stolen it won't cause you to reconfigure the other devices, you would simply deactivate that user.

While *most* benefits apply to multiple devices/user scenarios, there is one benefit for a single user, which is that it disables WPS, which is only available on personal.

I'm your case it seems like the benefit is minimal, and the overhead of setting up and maintaining a radius server likely isn't worth it.

Overview of enterprise http://techgenix.com/why-use-enterprise-wi-fi-security/

Comment: Thank you. I meant to mention in the question that WPS would be disabled anyway.